# Cannot review retracted and revised/resubmitted Doc proposal

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

I was looking over proposed edits on Docs, and I saw [one that was good material, but poorly arranged](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/42986?draftId=37142). I left a comment to that effect. You can't see it now, maybe because of this bug, but it was "This is great, but it looks like you're expecting the examples to be sequential; they aren't. Please consider combining them."

The proposer seems to have accepted my advice: that draft is retracted, and what appears to be a new, corrected version [has been proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/43312).

This is fantastic! Just one thing:

[image: Image of "Awaiting approval" box]

I'd really like to approve this proposal since it *makes the fixes* that I suggested originally! But review is disabled for me, and I'm not sure why.

I don't believe that I actually Rejected the earlier draft, and I'm 99% 
sure that I didn't touch the new one either. (There's certainly no entry for it in my profile's documentation actions tab.)

This seems like a bug, but I'm not sure whether my earlier interaction is just a coincidence. Or is there something by-design that prevents review of a later draft on the same topic by the same person if you've interacted?

Clarity please.

Comment: A typical SO tooltip on "STATUS: Awaiting approval" would be good, e.g. "user2 reviewed this H hours ago", or whatever.

Comment: Definitely annoying, especially since the review then still shows our original rejection after the approval, making it look like we're doing bad reviewing work. In some cases it's fine (i.e. when the content is unsalvageable), but in most cases I definitely want to be able to retract my vote. — Could you please draft a feature request for that to actually draw attention to it? (support is maybe the wrong tag…)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.  Retracted drafts that are subsequently resubmitted will be reviewable by the users who reviewed them pre-retraction.