# Why can't I approve or reject an edit after it has been retracted and improved?

Tags: support, documentation

After rejecting a suggested edit, the OP retracted their edit, incorporated my feedback, and resubmitted their edit. The new edit does not show "Approve" or "Reject" buttons for me. Does this mean I actually reject any iteration of that edit, or am I just barred from reviewing the new edit?

I don't really want to leave the suggestion hanging around, because it only takes a single approve to go through, and when everyone that would reject the edit would "wait for a while", that single approve will eventually show up. On the other hand, edits I reject usually are fixable. If OP fixed the issues I had with it, why can't I simply approve it in the next iteration?

Comment: Thank Dijkstra, [it's not just me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329227/cannot-review-retracted-and-revised-resubmitted-doc-proposal)! Except I don't think I actually formally rejected mine. So maybe not the same?

Comment: Does it show "status retracted"? I have had notifications of edits prompted by my requests for improvement show that and it was really confusing, especially since the edit was only  few minutes old

Comment: The first edit I voted on shows "status retracted". The second edit based on the first edit shows "waiting approval".